# Can Visual Studio 6.0 C++ run in Windows 11?

Tags: visual-c++-6, windows-11

I just install Windows 11 and found out the VS6.0 app I still have to support will not build. VS C++ 6.0 won't even launch. It was working fine in Windows 10.

Has anyone figured out how to run VS6 in Windows 11?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution on codeguru
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191047/Install-Visual-Studio-on-Windows?msg=5840158#xx5840158xx

I had VS6 running on Windows 10 so I only did 1 & 2 from "Works on Windows 11" comment.

*First, msdev.exe only showed the splash screen and then disappeared. It worked after

1. Renaming it to msdev1.exe (!)
2. Setting compatibility mode for Windows XP SP2.
3. Updating the file associations to point to the renamed exe file.*

Comment: after doing that does F1 help work inside Visual studio? I get an error message instead of the documentation for the function under the cursor.